# 404 error on Magento website and admin because of Invalid block type: Mage_Bd_Product_Slider_Block_Featured

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, 404-page, cpanel, magento-1.9.3.8

I was working on Magento 1.9.3.7 for a website.But when I clicked on clear cache it shows error and my website got down (404 error). I had an update at my Cpanel 
for Magento where my domain was in outdated installation. I updated it to 1.9.3.8 but still it shows the error

Please suggest me some solution,

```
2018-04-19T10:27:05+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Bd_Product_Slider_Block_Featured' in app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('bd_product_slid...', Array)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(179): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('bd_product_slid...', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(560): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<p>{{widget typ...')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php(123): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<p>{{widget typ...')
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->_toHtml()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('cms_page', true)
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#16 app/design/frontend/default/MAG080123/template/page/1column.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/subseatec...')
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#27 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#28 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

i have deleted my 404 error and got some store id error

```
Warning: Uncaught Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php:1377 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\Mage.php(353): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Helper\Data.php(47): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/log/enab...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\Mage.php(547): Mage_Log_Helper_Data->__construct() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\Mage.php(811): Mage::helper('log') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php(247): Mage::log('Warning: requir...', 3) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\Mage.php(690): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'require_once(C:...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 690, Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\Mage.php(690): require_once() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\pu in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php on line 1377

Fatal error: Mage::run(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\errors\404.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\local;C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\community;C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\code\core;C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\lib;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\public_html\app\Mage.php on line 690
```

Comment: can you check "var/log/exception.log" file and paster error here?

Comment: there is no such file in var/log

Comment: You need to enable error reporting on and load page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages

Comment: i have refereed the  above link and uncommented the link but did not got error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); also there is a magento install in same domain with /dir and it is giving an error                    [Wed Apr 18 13:27:12 2018] [error] [client 192.185.129.69] client denied by server configuration: /home/***/public_html/**/app/etc/local.xml

Comment: i have restored my backup and error log is set to yes now i am getting some mage error     2018-04-19T09:00:24+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Bd_Product_Slider_Block_Featured' in /home/subseatechnology/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/subseatechnology/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/subseatechnology/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout- the error is too long

Comment: You can edit your question and add error log. So we can debug.

Comment: Hi , Disable "Bd_Product_Slider_Block_Featured" extention for now and test site with clear cache.

Comment: You can disable it from "app/etc/modules/"

Comment: its work for you?

Comment: no it did not , i didnot got the files  Mage_Bd_Product_Slider_Block_Featured in app/etc/module folder but i got a file megnor_product_slider which i edited to false from true and deleted var/cache files  but didn't work..... also i had installed a new fresh magento 1.9.3.8 in my cpanel and when i perform cache clearing from admin panel it is again showing me the same error 404

Comment: Check for "Bd_EXTENTIONNAME" in "app/etc/modules/" and disable it

Answer (score 0):

Please run this query in database.

> SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE `core_store`
>   SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; UPDATE `core_store_group` SET
>   group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default'; UPDATE `core_website` SET
>   website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; UPDATE `customer_group` SET
>   customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN'; SET
>   FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: SQL query:

UPDATE core_store SET store_id =0 WHERE code =  'admin';


MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'prefix_database.core_store' doesn't exist      do i need to edit any think in above query before running the query

Comment: If you have table prefix then you need to add it before table name.